# Fixing Powershell Inactive User Script

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to produce a powershell script that will return all users in the root and flag them if there account is inactive for more than 15 days and/or 30 days. I think i'm close but my If/Elseif statements dont seem to be working. Does anyone know a way to improve this?

```
$objSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"

$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName")
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastLogonTimeStamp")


$userObjects = $objSearcher.FindAll() 

foreach ($user in $userObjects)
{
 $dn = $user.Properties.Item("displayName")
 $sam = $user.Properties.Item("sAMAccountName")
 $logon = $user.Properties.Item("lastLogonTimeStamp")

 if($logon.Count -eq 0)
 {
    $lastLogon = "Never"
 }
    #Inactive for 15 days
    elseif($logon.Value -ge (get-date).AddDays(-15))
  {
    $lastLogon = "Pending"
 }
    #Inactive for 30 days
      elseif($logon.Value -ge (get-date).AddDays(-30))
     {
        $lastLogon = "Retired"
     }

 else
 {
 $lastLogon = [DateTime]$logon[0]
 $lastLogon = $lastLogon.AddYears(1600)
 }


"""$dn"",$sam,$lastLogon"
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are identifying anyone who has logged on from -15 days to now as "Pending" and from -30 days to -15 days as "Retired".

Try flipping the order of your elseif's, and changing the greater than or equal check to a less than or equal.

You also need to cast $logon[0] to a DateTime, like you are doing in your "else" block.

So, your code will become:

```
elseif([DateTime]$logon[0] -le (get-date).AddDays(-30))
{
    #Inactive for 30 days
    $lastLogon = "Retired"
}
elseif([DateTime]$logon[0] -le (get-date).AddDays(-15))
{
    #Inactive for 15 days
    $lastLogon = "Pending"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Seth but with the script i have right now this is just changing all users to pending. I think it may have something to do with how im comparing the $logon.Value and (get-date).AddDays(-30).

Comment: `$LLTSlimit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15).ToFileTimeUTC().ToString()

$objSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(lastlogontimestamp<=$LLTSlimit))"`

Comment: @LinksTune I'm pretty sure the logic is right, maybe the condition isn't comparing two date types, for instance if $logon.Value is a string. Unfortunately I'm not somewhere I can test right now.

Comment: @LinksTune I finally was able to test it, I updated my answer. You needed to use a cast, like you were already doing in your else block.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for this :

```
"$LLTSlimit = **(Get-Date).AddDays(-15).ToFileTimeUTC().ToString()** $objSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556‌​.1.4.803:=2))(lastlogontimestamp<=$LLTSlimit))""
```

Finally, I found what I was looking for for a long time! You helped me a lot. Thanks!